# Eclipse P2 Profile Registry Looking in Wrong Directory

Tags: eclipse

When running Eclipse, I am getting a number of errors that all seem to share the same root cause:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Registry Directory not available: /home/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry  
at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.getProfileMap(LazyProfileRegistry.java:246)  
...
```

The profile registry does exist but the path is /home/[user]/p2/...
I'm trying to understand why eclipse is looking for the registry at /home instead of /home/[user].

This issue is causing various problems including being unable to open any of the SVN views or the "Install new Software" window.

I am using eclipse 4.10.

This issue started a few weeks ago when my devops team made some changes to the operating environment (I don't know the full extent of the changes). I'm hoping to understand how/why eclipse decides to look where it does for the P2 registry so I can help them identify which of the changes might have caused the problem.

Comment: That can be cause e.g. by building Eclipse without the [`-roaming`](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html) option or running a shared installation without `-configuration ...`. The current Eclipse version is 4.17 which means you are 7 releases behind (there is a separate [Stack Exchange for retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/)).

Comment: @howlger I am using -configuration and specifying my user directory. Also, 4.10 is only like 2 years old, that hardly qualifies as retrocomputing.

Comment: When someone else ran the shared installation without `-configuration` then the shared installation gets polluted (to be more precise, the `configuration` and the `p2` sub-folders). Is it a shared installation (used by you and others) and if yes, what is in the `configuration` folder of the shared installations directory? Regarding to your 7 release behind Eclipse, please do not waste time by using outdated software and please support Eclipse and other open source software by providing feedback on the current releases or preview builds.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'shared installation'. Eclipse is installed in a shared directory on our network but when I run it, -configuration is pointing at my home directory (and always has, to my knowledge). Similarly, when other people run eclipse, -configuration points at their home directory. I don't see any .eclipse folders in /home, and when I looked in the .eclipse folder in my user home looking for where the P2 directory might be defined, I only ever saw it referencing my user home directory.

Comment: What's in `<shared-eclipse-installation-directory>/configuration/`? There should be a `config.ini` file and several sub-folders. Please tell which sub-folders.

Comment: org.eclipse.core.runtime, org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme, org.eclipse.equinox.app, org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator, org.eclipse.oomph.setup, org.eclipse.osgi, org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal, org.eclipse.update, and .settings

Comment: As I already guessed, the shared Eclipse installation was at least once executed as non-shared/single-user (maybe to install one plugin for all, but that was the wrong way to do this). Now, the shared/multi-user Eclipse installation is broken for you and others and can from now on only be used as non-shared/single-user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224805/discussion-between-matts-and-howlger).

Comment: @howlger I have a fresh install of eclipse 2020-09 and I'm still having the same issue. My eclipse/configuration folder contains only config.ini, org.eclipse.update, and org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfiguration. It has never been run without the -configuration argument.

Comment: So, `<shared-eclipse-installation-directory>` is now as it should be, but you might still have stale files in your home directory (in your local configuration area and `p2` folder).

Comment: I wiped out ~/.p2 and ~/eclipse and am still having an issue. In fact, this time when launching eclipse, I got an error box saying 'Update job' has encountered a problem. The problem's root cause was "Registry directory not available: /home/p2" (I will point out that my home directory is not /home). So again, it seems to be coming to the same root issue of however eclipse is trying to identify the home folder is broken.